# Read 4 bytes a time with ifstream from binary file

Tags: c++, filereader, binaryfiles

I have a binary file that contains floats so that every 4 bytes are a float.
I'm not sure how I can read in a way that every four bytes would be stored as a float so I can do whatever I need with it.

Here's my code:

```
int main()
{
    float i;
    std::ifstream inFile("bin_file", std::ios::binary);
    while (inFile >> i)
    {
        std::cout << i;
    }
    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

In that case, it won't even enter the while loop unless I define i as a char. I guess that's because it reads 1 byte every time and can't store it as a float.
Btw I've checked and the file opens.

Thanks!

Comment: The first thing you need to do is determine endian-ness. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701624/difference-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-byte-order. `std:bit_cast` is c++20 is a good way to convert to floats.

Comment: See answer to [Reading binary file to unsigned char array and write it to another \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22129349/3422102) the question it is a duplicate of does not address the issue (how to handle binary input with `read()`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `operator>>` in streams is designed for formatted data (i.e. strings). You want to use [`read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) instead:

```cpp
int main()
{
    float i;
    std::ifstream inFile("bin_file", std::ios::binary);
    while(inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i), sizeof(i))) {
        std::cout << i;
    }
    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```